# PHP multiuser login class or script

Tags: php, class, authentication, scripting, multi-user

I am looking for a simple but secure login script with mySQL PHP: sessions, MD5 that I can use with my exsisting database.
Cookies to store password + password recovery by email.
Change login/pass.
I do not need registering, I register the user myself with temp login/pass.

table agents

- agent1
- agent2

table albums

- album1, owner: agent1
- album2, owner: agent1
- album3, owner: agent2
  ...

login.php
agent1 logs in and has access to his albums:
- album1
- album2

agent1 can edit his albums:
edit.php?ref=album1
but NOT edit.php?ref=album3 by changing the ?ref variable

Comment: Do you have any problems with your code so far?

Comment: I don't have any login code so far Felix.. Just looking for a class or script.

Comment: Well if you want to have code or a tutorial you should search for it with your favorite search engine first.

Comment: OMG is Google down again???? (I guess not - Results 1 - 10 of about 18,200,000 for php login script)

Comment: Allright allright, these kind of questions apparently are not welcome here..
Anyway for others looking for such a script I have found Access_user Class:
http://www.finalwebsites.com/snippets.php?id=10
Take it easy all.

Comment: Considering you don't have any code to get started with, this would be better suited to type into google, not post on here as a question saying gimme te codez..

Answer (score 0):

What you'll need to do is setup a method that checks login credentials for a particular agent.  "SELECT * FROM agents where username='$username' and password='$password', if a row is returned, you know they have successfully signed in.

From here, you must save some data to session variables like the username and id of the user.  You'll use this ID to check for album ownership in the album table.  When an agent tries to edit an album, it will check if the agent ID is consistent with the ID in the album table.

When an agent creates an album, you must save their id as maybe "agent_id" in the albums table to relate to in your code.